# Facebook Like Box Header missing if faces=false and stream=false

Tags: facebook, xfbml, facebook-likebox

I've inserted a like box into my page but I have a problem with it.

```
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/TermeszetBolond.Hu" width="176" show_faces="false" border_color="#befcbe" stream="false" header="true" height="140"></fb:like-box>
```

The like box is loaded, but the facebook header is missing.
You can see the result of this code on the left-middle of http://termeszetbolond.hu

Please heeelp... :)

Comment: this does seem to be a bug though, have you searched for bug listed related?

Comment: I've searched but didn't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: by default show faces is false so need to declare it, same with stream.

```
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/TermeszetBolond.Hu" width="176" header="true" height="140"></fb:like-box>
```